# Ideal points and the line at infinity

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

My textbook, *Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision* by Hartley and Zisserman says the following:

> **Ideal points and the line at infinity.** Homogeneous vectors $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$ such that $x_3 \not= 0$ correspond to finite points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. One may augment $\mathbb{R}^2$ by adding points with last coordinate $x_3 = 0$. The resulting space is the set of all homogeneous $3$-vectors, namely the projective space $\mathbb{P}^2$. The points with last coordinate $x_3 = 0$ are known as *ideal* points, or points at infinity. The set of all ideal points may be written $(x_1, x_2, 0)^T$, with a particular point specified by the ratio $x_1 : x_2$. Note that this set lies on a single line, the *line at infinity*, denoted by the vector $\mathbf{l}_{\infty} = (0, 0, 1)^T$. Indeed, one verifies that $(0, 0, 1)(x_1, x_2, 0)^T = 0$.
>
> Using result 2.2 one finds that a line $\mathbf{l} = (a, b, c)^T$ intersects $\mathbf{l}_{\infty}$ in the ideal point $(b, -a, 0)^T$ (since $(b, -a, 0)\mathbf{l} = 0$). A line $\mathbf{l}' = (a, b, c')^T$ *parallel* to $\mathbf{l}$ intersects $\mathbf{l}_{\infty}$ in the same ideal point $(b, -a, 0)^T$ irrespective of the value of $c'$. In inhomogeneous notation, $(b, -a)^T$ is a vector tangent to the line, and orthogonal to the line normal $(a, b)$, and so represents the line's *direction*. As the line's direction varies the ideal point $(b, -a, 0)^T$ varies over $\mathbf{l}_\infty$. For these reasons the line at infinity can be thought of as the set of directions of lines in the plane.

My confusion is with regards to this part:

> In inhomogeneous notation, $(b, -a)^T$ is a vector tangent to the line, and orthogonal to the line normal $(a, b)$, and so represents the line's *direction*. As the line's direction varies the ideal point $(b, -a, 0)^T$ varies over $\mathbf{l}_\infty$. For these reasons the line at infinity can be thought of as the set of directions of lines in the plane.

Specifically, it is not clear to me as to precisely which line the author is referring to:

> In inhomogeneous notation, $(b, -a)^T$ is a vector tangent to the line, and orthogonal to the line normal $(a, b)$, and so represents the line's *direction*.

If my understanding is correct, the inhomogeneous vector $(b, -a)^T$ is **normal** to the line $\mathbf{l}$ (and $\mathbf{l}'$) described by the vector $(a, b, c)$ (or $(a, b, c')$ in the case of $\mathbf{l}'$), and the inhomogeneous vector $(a, b)^T$ is the **tangent** to the same lines (and so represents the direction of the lines). However, this is phrased differently from what the author has written, and, given the vagueness of this part, it is unclear what line the author is precisely referring to.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the inhomogeneous vector $(a,b)$ is normal to the line $\mathbf l = (a,b,c)^T$. Go back to how this homogeneous vector representation of a line is defined: The line is the set of all points $\mathbf x$ such that $\mathbf l^T\mathbf x=0$. Expanded, this equation is $ax+by+c=0$, which is just the (I hope) familiar point-normal equation of the line.

The point of this passage is that each ideal point corresponds to a unique direction in the plane; all lines go in this direction intersect at that ideal point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was drawing upon the (what I understand to be) geometric fact that the normal to any vector $(a, b)$ is $(-b, a)$. Is this not valid in projective space (is it only valid in Euclidean space)?

Comment: “Normal” isn’t an invariant of projective transformations, so, strictly speaking, no. However, in this passage you’re augmenting the Euclidean plane, so those inhomogeneous vectors are indeed orthogonal. The mistake you made was in thinking that $(a,b)$ was parallel to the line $(a,b,c)^T$.

Comment: I don't understand. 1. The text says that $(b, -a)$ is **tangent** to the line $(a, b, c)^T$; how can this be true if, as we claim, $(b, -a)$ is **normal** to $(a, b, c)^T$? 2. And, with regards to what you said in your answer, the author says that the line is the set of all points $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, 0)^T$ such that $\mathbf{\mathbf{l}_\infty}\mathbf{x} = (0, 0, 1)(x_1, x_2, 0)^T = 0$. You're using the line $\mathbf l = (a,b,c)^T$ and stating that $\mathbf l^T\mathbf x=0$, but this isn't what the author said? [...]

Comment: [...] 3. Furthermore, how is it that the vector $(b, -a)^T$ be tangent to $(a, b, c)^T$? This isn't clear to me.

Comment: And to add another point : 4. If we take your line $\mathbf l^T\mathbf x = 0 \Rightarrow ax + by + c = 0$, then we have that, after taking the partial derivatives of this line, we have the (non-unit) tangent vector $(a, b)$.

Comment: Ok, my last comment made me realize something. As you said, if $\mathbf l^T\mathbf x=0$, then $\mathbf{x}$ is the set of points $(x, y, 1)$ (which is the vector $(x/1 y/1) = (x, y)$ in inhomogeneous coordinates) that are normal to the line $\mathbf{l}$. Therefore, $ax + by + c = 0$ is the line of these points, and so it is the line normal to the line represented by the points $\mathbf{l}$. If we take the partial derivatives of this line, then we get the tangent vector to this normal line $(a, b)$. [...]

Comment: [...] Therefore, since $(a, b)$ is **tangent** to the line $ax + by + c = 0$ that is normal to the line $\mathbf{l}$, then it must indeed be **normal** to the line $\mathbf{l}$!

Comment: And since the author references $(a, b)$ as being the line normal, the line it is referencing must be the line $\mathbf{l} = (a, b, c)^T$!

Comment: And by the basic geometric fact I mentioned earlier, we know that the inhomogeneous vector $(b, -a)^T$ is indeed tangent to the line $\mathbf{l}$, as the author claims, since we just found that the vector $(a, b)$ normal to it is tangent to the line $ax + by + c = 0$, which is the line normal to $\mathbf{l}$!